# Using Gazebo Simulator with ROSARIA

Tags: ros, gazebo, rosaria, p3at

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorial in http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA#Topics_and_Commands on "How to Use ROSARIA", under the section "Using MobileSim simulator", it is stated that for more fully featured simulation, one must use  stdr_simulator, Stage or Gazebo instead. However details on how to go about using these simulators with ROSARIA are not given.

Please assist me on how to go about doing this, particularly using Gazebo with ROSARIA. I have a Pioneer3AT simulation running in Gazebo, but when I attempt running the ROSARIA node, it returns the error:

bongzaseko@bongzaseko-OptiPlex-9020:~/GoogleDrive/ros/rosaria/catkin_ws$ rosrun rosaria RosAria
[ INFO] [1489585096.015996023]: RosAria: set port: [localhost:11311]
Connnecting to robot using TCP connection to localhost:11311...
Connected to remote host localhost through tcp.

Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Could not connect, no robot responding.
Failed to connect to robot.
[ERROR] [1489585102.454210966, 813.697000000]: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot! (Check ~port parameter is correct, and permissions on port device, or any errors reported above)
[FATAL] [1489585102.454259591, 813.697000000]: RosAria: ROS node setup failed...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257057/using-gazebo-simulator-with-rosaria/) by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason RosAria works with MobileSim is that MobileSim emulates the robot's controller firmware interface, so the interface between RosAria and MobileSim is the same as the interface between RosAria and a real robot.   Gazebo and the other simulators operate differently, and replace RosAria.   See the Gazebo documentation for information on how it works and how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-21**:
Thanks Reed. I thought the Gazebo simulator would also emulate the ARCOS firmware and be accessible via ARIA for client applications. I didn't know that it completely replaces it. What I need is to have a mirrored implementation of algorithms on both the Gazebo Simulation and the actual robot.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2017-03-24**:
Your client nodes with your application logic or higher level  control implementations can be the same if they use the standard interfaces to interact with both ROSARIA and Gazebo (e.g. `cmd_vel`, `pose`, and other comon topics.)

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-24**:
OK, Please clarify for me how I can do that since the ROS topics my client nodes have to subscribe to or publish on for the Gazebo simulation and the actual robot are different(or maybe more properly - have different namespaces).

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-24**:
OK, I think I get you now, so it is something to do with manipulating the namespaces of the topics in the code, probably through relative names?

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2017-03-24**:
You can rename topics in ROS, this is usually called "remapping" the topic name.  Search here or the ROS wiki.

**Comment by [bongzaseko](https://answers.ros.org/users/29704/bongzaseko/) on 2017-03-24**:
Alright, that clears it, thanks Reed